# android webView drag and drop

Tags: android, webview, drag-and-drop

Now a webpage is loaded on the webView, when I press and hold a picture or a hyperlink on the webpage, it will trigger the dragAndDrop API of android, and there will be the following log, but I don't want it to start this drag and drop, I want it to be done by me Start this yourself. So the long press event of webView cannot be canceled, but if it is not cancelled, after the long press starts dragging, the page is stuck and can only slide. Why is this?
The blue circle is my native API for receiving drag events, how can I prevent the webview from starting by itself?[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it seems that I have been subscribing to the drag event. If I cancel the subscription, I will not be stuck on the page after the drag initiated by the webview, so I will do this temporarily and start subscribing when I am ready to start dragging , unsubscribe after receiving the End event.
[image]
[image]